# Getting timeout error while login using Firebase API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, sentry

> A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

This error always occurs whenever I am trying to login.

My JS code:

```
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailId, password).then(function (userData) {
            usersRef.child(userData.uid).once("value", function (userSnap) {
                var usersSnap = userSnap.val();
                /*
                 * Record login attempt to firebase
                 */
                if (userSnap) {
                  authlogRef.child(userData.uid).once('value', function (userLogSnap) {
                    userLogSnap = userLogSnap.val();
                    // Initial login count
                    var loginCount = userLogSnap && userLogSnap.loginCount || 0;
                    // timestamp for current login
                    var timestamp = Date.now();
                    // log data to update
                    var data = userLogSnap || {};
                    //If no timestamps -> First login attempt, so timestamps -> []
                   if (!data.timestamps) {
                     data['timestamps'] = []
                   }
                   // push current timestamp for current login
                    data.timestamps.push(timestamp)
                    // increment login count
                    data['loginCount'] = loginCount + 1;
                    // set data to end point
                    authlogRef
                      .child(userData.uid)
                      .set(data)
                      .then(function () {
                        callback(null, usersSnap);
                      })
                  })
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
                    var msg = 'Email id is not Valid';
                    callback(msg);
                } else if (errorCode == 'auth/user-disabled') {
                    var msg = 'User is in disable state';
                    callback(msg);
                } else if (errorCode == 'auth/user-not-found') {
                    var msg = 'User not found';
                    callback(msg);
                } else if (errorCode == 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    var msg = 'Invalid Password';
                    callback(msg);
                } else if (errorCode == 'auth/network-request-failed') {
                    var msg = 'Network Error';
                    callback(msg);
                } else {
                    callback("error:" + errorMessage);
                }
            });
})
```

Sometimes I'm getting a timeout error. But I can't point out what is wrong.

Comment: Hey @ankit, can you check the network console and provide the details on what is timing out as this could happen for many reasons.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for reply, error is getting in client computer.I donot have any access.In my system it is properly working.Very rare case,I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I've just confirmed that one way this error occurs if the user has noscript (or presumably any other script blocking extension) installed on their browser.   If authentication is working for most users but others are getting this error message, this is likely the source of the issue.

Having the user whitelist whichever domain(s) you're using (including the OAuth domains when relevant), and/or disabling their script blocker, may solve the problem.